Why is the value in this dictionary's list of tuples not printing?
I am trying to print the value of a key when a float string is entered.
Here's my code:
number_dict = {1: 'One', 2: 'Two', 3: 'Three', 4: 'Four', 5: 'Five', 6: 'Six', 7: 'Seven', 8: 'Eight', 9: 'Nine', 0: 'Zero', '-': 'Negative', '.': 'Point'}

number = input('Enter a number: ')
print(f'As Text:', end = ' ')
for char in number:
    for key, value in number_dict.items():
        if char == key:
            print(value, end = ' ')
        elif int(char) == key:
            print(value, end = ' ')

What am I doing wrong? Why aren't the values associated with the '.' and '-' keys printing? They should be accessed in the elif condition.
There is already a try and except block to account for the ValueError. I just didn't want to post the code in its entirety, but I am aware of the error and already accounted for.
Thank you for your help in advance!!

They do print, they print invalid literal for int() with base 10: '.'. What did you expect will happen when you try to convert them to an int?

The integer keys print just fine. I have tried switching the order of my if statement which I don't think would trigger an invalid literal for int(), and the code executed the exact same unintended way.

[ask] and [mre]

if  elif char == key:
print(value, end = ' ')
elif int(char) == key:
print(value, end = ' ') Gives the same results, and it shouldn't trigger the integer error if it ordered this way.

If by “Why are [sic] the values associated with the '.' and '-' keys printing?” you meant that there was an exception being thrown, you should [edit] that critical information into the question. The normal way to use a dict is for char in number: print(number_dict[char], end=' '), though. (For this to work, you’ll need to change your integer keys to strings, e.g. 1 to '1'. This isn’t the only solution, but it’s nice to have homogeneous key types (all strings) instead of some integers and some strings.)

Why do you iterate over the dictionary anyway? this is not how you get values from a dict?

No, I did not mean there was an exception being thrown out. I did not include my exception in the code that I posted, because it was already working correctly and accounted for. This code is all placed in a try block with Except, but I wasn't asking about that.

I can iterate over a dictionary list of tuples or I could iterate over list containing the values using the .values(). The same unintended results are happening. Do you have a better way?

@Carissa the point they are making is that dictionaries should be used to retreive the values directly, something like my_dict[key] or my_dict.get(key), iterating over them sort of defeats the point. Indeed, if you had, you'd have avoided this issue

I appreciate your answer, but here's the thing. value = number_dict[key]. I have written the code in that exact way, and I still get the same error. If you run the code as you suggested, you will get the same error too. I appreciate your feedback though!

@Carissa no you don't. You get a different error. Please always provide a [mcve]. There are a couple things going wrong here in different ways, and you keep changing aspects of the code you have, and also, not actually demonstrating he real code you are running. Please don't do that.

So, just think about what's happening, You are iterating over the dict. so on the first iteration, key == 1. So when char == '.'., then key == char is false. Then you get to int('.') hence the error (or actually, in your own code which you don't feel like showing us, the exception is caught and it fails silently)

I am only trying to understand.. if change value to number_dict[key], the output has not changed. I have ran my code as you suggested, and I get the same results so I am definitely truly not sure what you mean. I just want to fix the problem.

For us to really help you, you must provide a [mcve]. We have to be talking about the same code, even if it is just a reduced toy example, to communicate effectively. This is part of the guidelines of the site. But, you can try something like if char.isdigit(): prin(number_dict[int(char)]) with an else: print(number_dict[char]), or another approach is to have only strings in the dict to begin with. Usually you want to avoid mixing types in your containers

I am sorry for not showing my full code! lol. It's nothing personal, the exception was the easiest part for me. This is the only part that I wanted help from. I know it makes it harder to understand, so I do get it and I am appreciative of the help.

Ok, it's fine, but please understand we aren't asking for "full code", we are asking for a [mcve]. That isn't the same thign. If you want debugging help, you need to put in a little bit of effort to help us help you. Part of that is trying as hard as possible to create an example we can run by ourselves without having to guess what you are doing. removing irrelevant parts of your overall code is good! But we still need to be talking about the same code.

I've edited it and voted to re-open, but I think the issue is still fundamentally what I told you in my comment above, I'll repeat it here: "You are iterating over the dict. so on the first iteration, key == 1. So when char == '.'., then key == char is false. Then you get to int('.') hence the error ". Except instead, now, that error is caught in your except clause, but none of the conditions there are true in this case, since number is something like '3.4', which doesn't trigger your if or elif conditions in the except clause

And please don't tell us there is no indentation in your actual code, I presume your code isn't raising a SyntaxError, please in the future just fix it so there isn't an error in the code you provide in the question

@juanpa.arrivillaga No. The indentation error was obvious. As I said, that only happened when I copied the code here and attempted to format. I've updated value to be number_dict[key] as you said and as I've already tried, and it still displays the unintended output that I am trying to fix.

For the record, I'm not iterating over a dictionary. number_dict.items() creates a list of tuples = [ (key, value)] for every key:value pair in the dictionary that the method is performed on.

That’s what iterating over a dictionary is. Standing by the solution in my original comment, btw (note the part about changing the keys of the dictionary to strings, which is necessary to make it work). You should avoid try, because it turns all of the various problems into the same behavior.

@juanpa.arrivillaga I mean this sincerely. Thank you for your help and helping me re-open the question. :) I know it wasn't easy dealing with me as a beginner. I hope you know your feedback was noted and appreciated. I will remember that .items() technically returns a dictionary item. So sorry for the back and forth. I was just frustrated myself, and I know that didn't make explaining easier for you. I think I just looked at the code too long and needed a break to think clearer. I hope you believe I mean that.

This loop will never run more than once because it ends with a break:
for key, value in number_dict.items():
    if char == key:
        print(number_dict[key], end = ' ')
    elif int(char) == key:
        print(number_dict[key], end = ' ')
    break

The break doesn’t make any sense. Once you remove that, you get to the main problem, which is that if int(char) throws an exception (like it does when you pass it the "-" or "." characters), you’re catching the exception outside the loop. This also means that the loop doesn’t run for the remaining items of the dictionary.
To understand what’s happening better, using a debugger, step through the loop with char = "-".
Now, you can fix this by catching the exception inside the loop:
for key, value in number_dict.items():
    if char == key:
        print(number_dict[key], end = ' ')
    else:
        try:
            if int(char) == key:
                print(number_dict[key], end = ' ')
        except ValueError:
            pass  # do nothing

But none of this is how you should use a dictionary. Dictionaries are for looking things up directly by key; by iterating over it to check every key, you’re defeating the point. To clean up your code, I would recommend starting by making your dict keys homogeneous, i.e. all strings instead of a mix of strings and integers:
number_dict = {'1': 'One', '2': 'Two', '3': 'Three', '4': 'Four', '5': 'Five', '6': 'Six', '7': 'Seven', '8': 'Eight', '9': 'Nine', '0': 'Zero', '-': 'Negative', '.': 'Point'}

Now you can get the value corresponding to any character, regardless of whether it’s a digit, with number_dict[char].
It’s also good practice to avoid throwing and catching exceptions when possible, and when you do have to, to make the try cover as little as possible – otherwise, you risk catching things you didn’t expect and mishandling them.
while True:
    number = input('Enter a number: ')

    # can check this ahead of time! helps limit the `try` responsibilities
    if ',' in number:
        print('Please try again without entering commas.')
        continue

    # much smaller `try`!
    try:
        float(number)
    except ValueError:
        print(f'"{number}" is not a valid number. Please try again.')
        continue

    print(f'As Text:', end = ' ')
    for char in number:
        print(number_dict[char], end = ' ')

Finally, note that float accepts some things you didn’t account for, like constants "-inf"/"inf"/"nan", scientific notation "1e-1", and whitespace. You should use stricter validation, which also means not needing a try at all (good!). Here’s an example of doing it with regular expressions:
import re

number_dict = {'1': 'One', '2': 'Two', '3': 'Three', '4': 'Four', '5': 'Five', '6': 'Six', '7': 'Seven', '8': 'Eight', '9': 'Nine', '0': 'Zero', '-': 'Negative', '.': 'Point'}

while True:
    number = input("Enter a number: ")

    if "," in number:
        print("Please try again without entering commas.")
        continue

    if not re.fullmatch(r"-?(?!\.?\Z)[0-9]*(?:\.[0-9]*)?", number):
        print(f"{number!r} is not a valid number. Please try again.")
        continue

    text = " ".join(number_dict[char] for char in number)
    print(f"As Text: {text}")

but since you probably don’t know regular expressions yet, try writing a strict validation function as an exercise, with a loop and the str.isdigit method you’ve already used. Consider questions like whether "1." should print “One Point” or “One” or an error!
